# Returning average rating from a database (SQL)

Tags: php, sql, database, rating-system

I'm trying to create a rating system, where the user can rate pictures/videos/audio etc. I have two tables at the moment

```
Table: products
Cols:  product_id[PK] | name | category | type | link
```

This is the products table and contains information about the products. If you're confused by products, think of the "product" as the image/video/audio, I named it like this simply for allowing me to understand it easier. The second table is the ratings

```
Table: product_ratings
Cols:  rating_id[PK] | rating | product_id | timestamp
```

This table stores information about the rating the user has given.

I want a page where it will display the highest rating (on average) for all "products". So far, I've looked through SA, and found the follow piece of code:

```
SELECT
p.product_id, p.name,
AVG(pr.rating) AS rating_average
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_ratings pr
ON pr.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.product_id = 1
```

This just returns the average rating for a specific product_id, How would I go about getting ALL the product_ids and their average rating, and how would I find the highest one via PHP?

I've tried:

```
WHERE p.product_id < 1 AND p.product_id < 30
```

But this just returns product_id of 2, with it's name and average_rating, which I don't understand.

Guidance/links to material are welcome

Comment: Why are you giving "where p.product_id=1" ?

Comment: This was just to demonstrate that the SQL given returns the avg rating for that specified product ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
    p.product_id,
    p.name,
    AVG(pr.rating) AS rating_average
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_ratings pr
ON pr.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY rating_average DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I am just too slow on typing lol This is exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this seems to be doing what I wanted originally. Will look around now to see how to select the first item in the list (i.e. The highest rated product).

Comment: You might as well use Mark's query as a subselect for a `from` clause, that way, you will be able to get a `MAX(rating_aberage)` over your avering rating results.

Comment: Which database doesn't require all non-aggregate fields in the group by?

Answer (score 4):

Just try:

```
SELECT
p.product_id, p.name,
AVG(pr.rating) AS rating_average
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_ratings pr
ON pr.product_id = p.product_id
```

also this is meaningless expression:

```
WHERE p.product_id < 1 AND p.product_id < 30
```

because it is completely equivalent to

```
WHERE p.product_id < 1
```

and i doubt that you have ids below zero

Comment: I did mean more than 1 and less than 30, I got confused I think

Comment: which database doesn't require a group by?

Comment: Scary! So what name does it use? Indeterminate? Is it actually grouping by the name, you just don't need to specify it in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is close. Just remove the WHERE clause that filters everything.

```
SELECT     p.product_id, p.name,
           AVG(pr.rating) AS rating_average
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_ratings pr
ON pr.product_id = p.product_id
ORDER BY rating_average DESC
```

This will return you the averages for each product, sorted with the highest average rating at the top of the resultset.

Comment: This only displays 1 row for some reason, see Mark Byers above, his seems to list all of the product_id's that have been rated before